# Programmatically adding two buttons to each row as it loads

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a `ListView` in a new `WPF` window and also a function that populates the ListView when it is called. This function just takes the URL of my web server where I've stored the data, increments the "id" and gets the data and stores it in the ListView. Therefore it populates the ListView with a certain number of items.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to add two buttons, ON & OFF, to each ListView item as it gets populated programmatically. i.e, if 16 items are added, I want 2 buttons for each item, and if it's 12 items, the similar procedure. Here's my code:

```
namespace user_login
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Window1 W = new Window1();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        public void populate()
        {
            int i;
            int num = 16;

            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                string val = Convert.ToString(i);
                string currentUrl = "http://xpleria.com/devices.php?query=dev&id=";
                string newUrlWithChangedSort = ReplaceQueryStringParam(currentUrl, "id", val);
                string result = getcontent(newUrlWithChangedSort);    
                W.list1.Items.Add(result);
            }
        }

        public string getcontent(string URL)
        {
            string content = "";

            // Get HTML data
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            try
            {
                content = client.DownloadString(URL);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No Connection detected!!!");
            }
            return content;
        }

        public static string ReplaceQueryStringParam(string currentPageUrl, string paramToReplace, string newValue)
        {
            string urlWithoutQuery = currentPageUrl.IndexOf('?') >= 0
                ? currentPageUrl.Substring(0, currentPageUrl.IndexOf('?'))
                : currentPageUrl;

            string queryString = currentPageUrl.IndexOf('?') >= 0
                ? currentPageUrl.Substring(currentPageUrl.IndexOf('?'))
                : null;

            var queryParamList = queryString != null
                ? HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
                : HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            if (queryParamList[paramToReplace] != null)
            {
                queryParamList[paramToReplace] = newValue;
            }
            else
            {
                queryParamList.Add(paramToReplace, newValue);
            }

            return String.Format("{0}?{1}", urlWithoutQuery, queryParamList);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string user = textbox1.Text;
            string password = textbox2.Password;
            string currentUrl = "http://xpleria.com/login.php?query=login&user=wcam&pass=wireless";
            string newUrlWithChangedSort = ReplaceQueryStringParam(currentUrl, "user", user);
            string newUrl = newUrlWithChangedSort;
            string FinalUrl = ReplaceQueryStringParam(newUrl, "pass", password);
            string result= getcontent(FinalUrl);
            string value = result.Substring(0, 8);

            string invalid = "xpleria0";
            string valid = "xpleria1";

            if (value.Equals(invalid))
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("The Username and/or Password you have entered is invalid, please try again");
            }
            else if (value.Equals(valid))
            {
                string sessionID = result.Substring(8, 32);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("HI, WELCOME CLETA");
                this.Close();

                using (new user_login.loading.PleaseWait(this.Location))
                {
                    W.Show();
                    populate();
                }
            }
        }

        public System.Drawing.Point Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `DataTemplate` for the `ListView` which shows a `ListViewItem` the way you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to recommend you take a step back and start giving some serious consideration to organizing your code. I realize this isn't an answer to the question you asked but it *is* the  answer to the question you should be asking.

First of all, all code relating to the retrieval of these items from the URL should be moved into a class of some kind. This class should accept the URL string as a constructor parameter and gather all the appropriate data. You should then create another class which you will use to populate with the data for each individual item and then expose this list. By the time you're done the code in your window should little more complex than:

```
var ItemsGetter = new ItemsGetter(URL);
foreach(var Item in ItemsGetter.Items)
{
    // Populate the ListView
}
```

Once you're done with that I recommend you create a UserControl. User controls are extremely useful in situations where you need to represent a dynamic number of data entities each with their own set of controls which allow operations to be performed on each one. You should create a UserControl with a label and the two buttons you need. The UserControl's constructor should expect a parameter of the data type you created to represent each one of your classes. From there you can have the buttons operate on the data type as necessary.

Finally, you'll probably need a way to have the UserControl interact with the Window. Say for example one of your buttons is "Delete". You'd probably want the item to disappear from the list once the operation is complete. Don't be tempted to tie in your control with the Window by passing it as a parameter or something. Instead, read up on `Action` events and learn how you can create an event on the user control which you bind in the foreach loop of the Window when you're populating the list view. When the UserControl has completed the delete operation triggered by the button you can raise the UserControl's event which will prompt the Window to remove the control from the List View.

Last but not least, **NAME YOUR CONTROLS**.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: *Last but not least, NAME YOUR CONTROLS.* - Why should he do that? I'm also trying to avoid naming whenever I can. But perhaps you can provide some arguments to reconsider this approach.

Comment: @DHN - Which makes more sense: `string user = textbox1.Text;` or `string user = txtUsername.Text;`?

Comment: Neither the one nor the other, just don't access controls in code behind, so you won't need names. ;o) - Joking aside, you're right. If you have to access controls in codebehind, it's much better to have readable names.

Comment: THANKS A LOT PAL , THAT HELPED. ANY SPECIFIC SITE U MAy HAVE REGARDING USER CONTROLS??? AND HOW THEY"RE CREATED??